# Adjust text manually

Tags: spacing

I'm writing my thesis. I made some appendices with tables. But, I want to adjust some lines of text manually. Some lines should be pass to next page. Is it possible ?

Sould I use `vspace` ?

Sorry for my long code. I want to put the text between tables.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,openright]{report}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage[inner=3cm,outer=2cm,tmargin=2.0cm,bmargin=2.0cm, includefoot, includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{booktabs, multicol, multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ghsystem}
\usepackage{chemgreek}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{layouts}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\renewcommand\chaptername{Anexo}
\addto\captionsportuguese{%
  \renewcommand\appendixname{Anexo}
  \renewcommand\appendixpagename{Anexos}
}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\newcolumntype{,}{D{,}{,}{-2}}
\newcommand{\mc}{\multicolumn}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}


\appendixpage
\begin{appendices}
\fancyhead[RO]{\slshape \leftmark}


\chapter{Caracterização de folhas de papel}
\label{anexos_folhas}

As propriedades estruturais, mecânicas e ópticas de cada série de folhas produzidas estão representadas nas Tabelas \ref{tabela_H60_folhas_anexos}, \ref{tabela_h90_folhas_anexos}, \ref{tabela_H90E_folhas_anexos} e \ref{tabela_30_folhas_anexos}.

A Tabela \ref{tabela_H60_folhas_anexos} representa as folhas produzidas com a carga mineral Hydrocarb\textsuperscript{\textregistered}, original e modificada.

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Propriedades estruturais, mecânicas e ópticas das folhas produzidas com GCC H60 original e modificado.}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ll*{4}{,}}
  \cmidrule[0.8pt]{2-6}
   & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Amostra}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{H60 20}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{H60-M 20}} \\
   & & \multicolumn{1}{X}{\centering \textbf{1}}  &  \multicolumn{1}{X}{\centering \textbf{2}}  &  \multicolumn{1}{X}{\centering \textbf{1}}   &  \multicolumn{1}{X}{\centering \textbf{2}} \\
   \cmidrule{2-6}
  \multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=C]{90}{Estruturais}} & \textbf{\textit{Filler} Efectivo (\si{\%)}} & 18,39 & 18,25  & 17,56  & 17,07 \\
  & \textbf{Gramagem (\si{g.m^{-2}})} & 83,78  & 85,02  & 82,82  & 83,02 \\
  & \textbf{Índice de Mão (\si{cm^3.g^{-1}})} & 1,40  & 1,38   & 1,50   & 1,51 \\
  & \textbf{Massa Volúmica (\si{g.cm^{-3}})} & 0,72  & 0,72   & 0,67   & 0,66 \\
  & \textbf{Resistência ao ar Gurley 100ml (\si{s})} & 3,81   & 5,32   & 4,09   & 3,37 \\
  & \textbf{Rugosidade  ar Bendtsen, FL (\si{ml.min^{-1}})} & 191,77   & 199,75 & 414,14 & 410,20 \\
\addlinespace
  \multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=C]{90}{Mecânicas}} & \textbf{Índice de Rebentamento (\si{kPa.m^2.g^{-1}})} & 1,76  & 2,09   & 2,34   & 2,32 \\
  &  \textbf{Índice de Tracção (\si{N.m.g^{-1}})} & 34,60  & 37,18  & 42,51  & 43,42 \\
  &  \textbf{Extensão (\si{\%})} & 2,86   & 2,72   & 2,77   & 2,62 \\
  &  \textbf{Tensile Stiffness (\si{kN.m^{-1}})} & 534,60  & 521,73 & 593,68 & 609,64 \\
  &  \textbf{Índice T.E.A. (\si{J.m.g^{-1}})} & 0,74   & 0,74   & 0,86   & 0,83 \\
  &  \textbf{Índice de Rasgamento (\si{mN.m^2.g^{-1})}} & 5,62   & 5,74   & 5,72   & 5,50 \\
\addlinespace
 \multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=C]{90}{Ópticas}} &    \textbf{C.E.D.L. (\si{m^2.kg^{-1})}} & 48,52  & 47,59  & 43,41  & 43,74 \\
 &  \textbf{Opacidade (\si{\%)}} & 88,10  & 88,09  & 86,25  & 85,94 \\
 &   \textbf{Brancura R457 (\si{\%)}} & 84,59  & 84,95  & 84,62  & 85,77 \\
    \cmidrule[0.8pt]{2-6}
    \end{tabularx}%
  \label{tabela_H60_folhas_anexos}%
\end{table}%

Na Tabela \ref{tabela_h90_folhas_anexos} estão apresentadas as propriedades relativas às folhas produzidas com carbonato de cálcio H90.

\begin{table}[ht]
  \caption{Propriedades estruturais, mecânicas e ópticas das folhas produzidas com GCC H90 original e modificado.}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ll*{4}{,}}
  \cmidrule[0.8pt]{2-6}
   & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Amostra}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{H90 20}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{H90-M 20}} \\
   & & \multicolumn{1}{X}{\centering \textbf{1}}  &  \multicolumn{1}{X}{\centering \textbf{2}} &  \multicolumn{1}{X}{\centering \textbf{1}} &  \multicolumn{1}{X}{\centering \textbf{2}}  \\
   \cmidrule{2-6}
  \multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=C]{90}{Estruturais}} & \textbf{\textit{Filler} Efectivo (\si{\%)}}  & 17,47 & 17,49  & 17,63  & 17,43 \\
  & \textbf{Gramagem (\si{g.m^{-2}})} & 82,82 & 83,37  & 84,81  & 81,31 \\
  & \textbf{Índice de Mão (\si{cm^3.g^{-1}})} & 1,35  & 1,36   & 1,45   & 1,59 \\
  & \textbf{Massa Volúmica (\si{g.cm^{-3}})}   & 0,74   & 0,73   & 0,69 & 0,63 \\
  & \textbf{Resistência ao ar Gurley, 100 ml (\si{s)}}    & 5,57   & 5,56   & 4,93 & 3,54 \\
  & \textbf{Rugosidade  ar Bendtsen, FL (\si{ml.min^{-1}})}    & 202,75 & 206,63 & 342,20 & 725,63 \\
\addlinespace
\addlinespace
 \multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=C]{90}{Mecânicas}} & \textbf{Índice de Rebentamento (\si{kPa.m^2.g^{-1}})}  & 1,87  & 1,83   & 2,16   & 2,27 \\
  &  \textbf{Índice de Tracção (\si{N.m.g^{-1}})} & 33,71  & 31,80  & 41,70  & 42,34 \\
  &  \textbf{Extensão (\si{\%})}    & 2,64   & 2,62   & 2,83 & 2,73 \\
  &  \textbf{Tensile Stiffness (\si{kN.m^{-1}})}  & 515,61 & 516,72 & 604,35 & 561,57 \\
  &  \textbf{Índice T.E.A. (\si{J.m.g^{-1}})}  & 0,67   & 0,62   & 0,88 & 0,83 \\
  &  \textbf{Índice de Rasgamento (\si{mN.m^2.g^{-1})}} & 5,28   & 5,19   & 5,17   & 5,40 \\
\addlinespace
\addlinespace
 \multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=C]{90}{Ópticas}} &   \textbf{C.E.D.L. (\si{m^2.kg^{-1})}} & 49,89  & 49,27  & 46,97  & 44,46 \\
  &  \textbf{Opacidade (\si{\%})}   & 88,41  & 89,58  & 87,52 & 85,92 \\
  &   \textbf{Brancura R457 (\si{\%)}}  & 85,74  & 82,83  & 85,63  & 85,79 \\
    \cmidrule[0.8pt]{2-6}
    \end{tabularx}%
  \label{tabela_h90_folhas_anexos}%
\end{table}%

A Tabela \ref{tabela_H90E_folhas_anexos} contêm novamente as propriedades da folha avaliadas neste tese em relação ao Hydrocarb\textsuperscript{\textregistered} H90 E.

\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \caption{Propriedades estruturais, mecânicas e ópticas das folhas produzidas com GCC H90 E original e modificado.}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ll*{4}{,}}
  \cmidrule[0.8pt]{2-6}
   & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Amostra}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{H90E 20}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{H90E-M 20}} \\
  &   & \multicolumn{1}{X}{\centering \textbf{1}}  &  \multicolumn{1}{X}{\centering \textbf{2}} &  \multicolumn{1}{X}{\centering \textbf{1}} &  \multicolumn{1}{X}{\centering \textbf{2}}  \\
   \cmidrule{2-6}
 \multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=C]{90}{Estruturais}} & \textbf{\textit{Filler} Efectivo (\si{\%)}} & 17,44 & 17,84 & 16,58  & 16,34  \\
  & \textbf{Gramagem (\si{g.m^{-2}})} & 83,23 & 85,25 & 82,11  & 84,58   \\
  & \textbf{Índice de Mão (\si{cm^3.g^{-1}})}& 1,37 & 1,33  & 1,45   & 1,49  \\
  & \textbf{Massa Volúmica (\si{g.cm^{-3}})} & 0,73  & 0,75   & 0,69 & 0,67 \\
  & \textbf{Resistência ao ar Gurley, 100 ml (\si{s)}} & 4,63   & 9,09 & 3,86    & 4,53 \\
  & \textbf{Rugosidade  ar Bendtsen, FL (\si{ml.min^{-1}})} & 173,46   & 126,74 & 396,38 & 422,86 \\
\addlinespace
 \multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=C]{90}{Mecânicas}} & \textbf{Índice de Rebentamento (\si{kPa.m^2.g^{-1}})} & 1,93 & 2,31  & 2,43   & 1,57  \\
  &  \textbf{Índice de Tracção (\si{N.m.g^{-1}})}& 35,50 & 40,18  & 43,72 & 28,28  \\
  &  \textbf{Extensão (\si{\%})} & 2,71   & 3,05   & 2,81   & 1,91 \\
  &  \textbf{Tensile Stiffness (\si{kN.m^{-1}})} & 525,46  & 538,58 & 592,25 & 447,77 \\
  &  \textbf{Índice T.E.A. (\si{J.m.g^{-1}})} & 0,73   & 0,88   & 0,91 & 0,38 \\
  &  \textbf{Índice de Rasgamento (\si{mN.m^2.g^{-1})}}& 5,61 & 5,35   & 5,43   & 5,29  \\
\addlinespace
\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=C]{90}{Ópticas}} &    \textbf{C.E.D.L. (\si{m^2.kg^{-1})}}& 48,96 & 49,25  & 46,52  & 45,72   \\
  &  \textbf{Opacidade (\si{\%})} & 87,76  & 87,86  & 86,22  & 86,59  \\
  &  \textbf{Brancura R457 (\si{\%)}} & 85,92 & 86,68  & 87,54  & 86,84  \\
    \cmidrule[0.8pt]{2-6}
    \end{tabularx}%
  \label{tabela_H90E_folhas_anexos}%
\end{table}%

A Tabela \ref{tabela_30_folhas_anexos} mostras as propriedades das folhas produzidas com 30 \%(w/w) de carga mineral.

\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \caption{Propriedades estruturais, mecânicas e ópticas das folhas produzidas com 30 \%(w/w) de GCC H60 modificado e mistura PCC + GCC H60 modificado.}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ll*{4}{,}}
  \cmidrule[0.8pt]{2-6}
   & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Amostra}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{H60-M 30}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{H60-M+PCC}} \\
   &  & \multicolumn{1}{X}{\centering \textbf{1}}  &  \multicolumn{1}{X}{\centering \textbf{2}} &  \multicolumn{1}{X}{\centering \textbf{1}} &  \multicolumn{1}{X}{\centering \textbf{2}}  \\
   \cmidrule{2-6}
 \multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=C]{90}{Estruturais}} & \textbf{\textit{Filler} Efectivo (\si{\%)}} & 26,68 & 26,90 & 26,32  & 26,93  \\
  & \textbf{Gramagem (\si{g.m^{-2}})} & 82,49 & 82,47 & 83,01  & 83,65   \\
  & \textbf{Índice de Mão (\si{cm^3.g^{-1}})}& 1,48 & 1,47  & 1,52  & 1,53  \\
  & \textbf{Massa Volúmica (\si{g.cm^{-3}})} & 0,68  & 0,68   & 0,66 & 0,65 \\
  & \textbf{Resistência ao ar Gurley, 100 ml (\si{s)}} & 2,93   & 2,63 & 3,13    & 2,45 \\
  & \textbf{Rugosidade  ar Bendtsen, FL (\si{ml.min^{-1}})} & 394,86   & 421,38 & 385,83 & 420,00 \\
\addlinespace
 \multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=C]{90}{Mecânicas}} & \textbf{Índice de Rebentamento (\si{kPa.m^2.g^{-1}})} & 1,49 & 1,45  & 1,55   & 1,24  \\
  &  \textbf{Índice de Tracção (\si{N.m.g^{-1}})}& 27,31 & 27,17  & 23,91 & 25,43  \\
  &  \textbf{Extensão (\si{\%})} & 2,47   & 2,48   & 2,23   & 2,40 \\
  &  \textbf{Tensile Stiffness (\si{kN.m^{-1}})} & 457,61  & 456,87 & 433,30 & 437,26 \\
  &  \textbf{Índice T.E.A. (\si{J.m.g^{-1}})} & 0,50   & 0,49   & 0,40 & 0,47 \\
  &  \textbf{Índice de Rasgamento (\si{mN.m^2.g^{-1})}}& 4,11 & 4,13   & 3,99   & 3,90  \\
\addlinespace
\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=C]{90}{Ópticas}} &  \textbf{C.E.D.L. (\si{m^2.kg^{-1})}}& 49,69 & 49,81  & 55,39  & 55,60   \\
  &  \textbf{Opacidade (\si{\%})} & 87,97  & 89,78  & 89,28  & 90,99  \\
  &  \textbf{Brancura R457 (\si{\%)}} & 86,40 & 82,43  & 87,23  & 83,77  \\
    \cmidrule[0.8pt]{2-6}
    \end{tabularx}%
  \label{tabela_30_folhas_anexos}%
\end{table}%
\end{appendices} 


\end{document}
```

Comment: well without more context how would we know. It is not even clear what you want to achieve

Comment: Well, you seem to be here about 4 months: The name of the drill is `MWE` ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I just edited my question with the MWE. But, the code is very long

Comment: the whole point of the `table` environment is that latex can move it, so you can not put text in the main body that appears "between tables" if you have text that you want to always appear below the tabular put it _in_ the table environment so it floats with the table

Comment: Try to visit this website: http://www.tablesgenerator.com/ You can create your table in wysiwyg form and just click generate to have the equivalent latex code. It also has an option to compress all the white spaces.

Comment: If you do not want the table to move relative to your text, don't use table.  You can even use \captionof{table} from the caption package in the main body.  To prevent the caption from being separated from the tabular, put both into a minipage  {\textwidth}.